# Finding the logic expressions of a finite state machine that has three possible inputs

Tags: state-machines

I'm familiar with finite state machines when there are two possible states for input, which I will call `w.` That is, `w = 1` or `w = 0`. However, what about the situation in which `w` can equal `A, B, or C`? In this situation, I believe that I would have to represent the input with two bits, such that `A = 00`, `B = 01`, and `C = 11`.

For example, say I have to detect the sequence ABCB (using a Moore Machine). Below is a picture of the state diagram, state-table, and state-assignment table:

[image]

Here, I represent the present state with three bits, and the next state with three bits. Normally, I have no issue finding the required logic expressions using Karnaugh Maps given that `w = 1 or 0`. However, here `w = A, B, or C`. Assuming that I let `A = 00`, `B = 01`, and `C = 11`, how would I derive the appropriate logic expressions?

My inclination is to solve a 5-variable Karnaugh Map for each Next State flip-flop (i.e. `Y2, Y1, Y0`). For instance, `Y2` is some function of `y1, y2, y3, and w` that can be found using a Karnaugh Map.

Am I heading in the right direction with my reasoning here? Any constructive input is appreciated.

Note: This is related to an assignment of mine, but this is not the pattern I'm trying to detect.

Edit: Now that I thought about it some more, it seems like I really have 5 bits to work with in regard to the Karnaugh Map - which it technically four *variables* because `yn` represents 1 bit and `w` represents two bits.

Comment: Once you have worked this out manually you can verify your findings with [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/) which is free and very useful.

Comment: @David Regarding "manually," are you saying that my approach would work?

Comment: Sorry, I lack the knowledge to answer that.  I just thought it would be helpful to have some way of verifying results at a later date.

Comment: Ah, no problem. The tool you mentioned seems really useful. I'll check it out later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done, all what's left is to get the logic equations from the table. Remember that w is an input so it is part of the present state and we will use it to compute values of the next state.

Let w be a 2 bit number, $$w = w_1w_0$$

so if we let A = 00, B = 01, and C = 11 then:

$$
  w = \left.\begin{cases} \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
& w = A\\ \\ w_1 \bar{w_0} & w = B\\ \\
  w_1 w_0 & w = C \end{cases} \right\} \\ \\
$$

and the 5 states are
$$
  S_i = \left. \begin{cases} 
        \bar{y_2 }\bar{y_1 }\bar{y_0 }& i = 1 \\ \\
         \bar{y_2 }\bar{y_1 } y_0  & i = 2 \\ \\
         \bar{y_2 } y_1 \bar{y_0 } & i = 3 \\ \\
         \bar{y_2 } y_1 y_0 & i = 4 \\ \\
         y_2 \bar{y_1} \bar{y_0 } & i = 5
        \end{cases} \right\}
$$

To get the logic for computing the next state you get the boolean equation for each bit of the next state separately.E.g to get the logic for computing y0 :

$$
 y_{0 , next} = S_1 A + S_2 A + S_3A + S_3 C + S_4 A + S_5 A
$$

$$
 y_{0, next} =  \bar{y_2 }\bar{y_1 }\bar{y_0 } \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
      + \bar{y_2 }\bar{y_1 } y_0  \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
      + \bar{y_2 } y_1 \bar{y_0 } \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
      + \bar{y_2 } y_1 \bar{y_0 }  w_1 w_0 
      + \bar{y_2 } y_1 y_0  \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
      +  y_2 \bar{y_1} \bar{y_0 } \bar{w_1} \bar{w_0}
$$

which reduces to

$$
 y_{0, next} = \bar{w_1}\bar{w_0} + \bar{y_2 } y_1 \bar{y_0 }  w_1 w_0 
$$

Repeat this for y2 and y1, to get the rest of the combinational logic required.

The output(z) is high when this state machine is in state 5 so Z will be given by:

$$ 
  z = S_5 = y_2 \bar{y_1} \bar{y_0 }
$$

This is a moore machine as Z is only dependent on the current state.